# css ie8 issue position relative when scroll is act like absolute

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, scroll, positioning

I have a div with position "relative" and float:left,but when i scroll the page this div is acting like position "absolute".When i remove position "relative" the div is moving correctly when scrolling the page.
Many times i used div with position relative, and other div inside the parent with position absolute.But this issue i see it for a first time.This is really weird.I try to change the DOC Type to "strict" but this is not good solution for me.

Comment: please give your code for better understanding

Comment: Thanks for quick respond,but i am shame of myself.It's a my error in my css file.Still don't get it where is the error but i will fix it.

Comment: The problem is that my body has no position.And my content i so long that shows a scroll.In side my main div and all content is into this main div.I have a div with position relative.And when scrolling the page scroll correct except this div with relative position, he is acting like position static.I solve the problem just to set to my main div position relative.And everything go fine.

Comment: i met this issue for a first time, many times i use divs with relative position but they never act like this.I'm wondering is this samo kind a of new bug in ie.I'm talking for a IE8

Answer (score 5):

For IE7, you need to `position: relative;` the element that is scrolling to keep relatively positioned children from sticking.

Answer (score 0):

Your site may be displaying in compatibility view, or otherwise rendering as IE7. IE7 never quite liked position: relative elements, often fixing them to the page for no good reason.

Try adding a css rule

```
html { position: relative; }
```

and see if that fixes it.